# inner join of four table with mysql

Tags: mysql

I have four table.I want the result of inner join of four tables.My query is :

```
select 
    customer.id,
    customer.name,
    customer.opeing_balance,
    customer.opening_balance_type,
    sum(sale.total) as sum_total,
    sum(receipt.net_amount) as sum_net_amount, 
    sum(sale_return.total_return) as sum_sale_return 
from customer 
    inner join sale on customer.id=sale.cust_id 
    inner join receipt on customer.id=receipt.cust_id 
    inner join sale_return on customer.id=sale_return.cust_id 
group by customer.id
```

**table structure**

```
customer

id   name   opening_balance    opening_balance_type
26   neena    50                  debit
27   shan     50                  debit


sale

cust_id         total
27               50
27               50
26               60
26               40

receipt

cust_id     net_amount
 27            10
 27            10
 26            50
 26             10

sale_return

cust_id         total_return
 27                10
 27                20
 26                15
 26                20
```

Result

name   opening_balance    opening_balance_type  sum_total  sum_net_amount sum_sale_return
neena    50                 debit               100         60               35
shan     50                 debit               100         20               30

I want the customer_name,opeing_balance,opening_balance_type,sum of total,sum of net_amount,sum of total_retun of each customer.Anybody give any hep?

Comment: It's unclear what specific help you're looking for:  does the query fail with an error?  Produce incorrect results?  Something else?  You've written a query and some tables, but no actual question.

Comment: produce incorrect error

Comment: I can't tell whether you mean that the query fails with an error (doesn't run at all), or runs and produces results, but the results are incorrect.

Comment: produce incorrect result

Comment: I don't think you want a join at all. But just to be sure, please provide the desired result.

Comment: ok ,i will add the result

Comment: added the result table structure ,plz  look it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, try this:

```
select 
    customer.id,
    customer.name,
    customer.opeing_balance,
    customer.opening_balance_type,
    s.total,
    r.net_amount,
    s_r.total_return
from customer INNER JOIN
    (SELECT cust_id,SUM(total) total FROM sale GROUP BY cust_id) s ON s.cust_id = customer.id INNER JOIN
    (SELECT cust_id,SUM(net_amount) net_amount FROM receipt GROUP BY cust_id) r ON r.cust_id = customer.id INNER JOIN
    (SELECT cust_id,SUM(total_return) total_return FROM sale_return GROUP BY cust_id) s_r ON s_r.cust_id = customer.id
```

[SQLFiddle demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69950d/1/0)

Comment: shows these error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT cust_id,SUM(net_amount) net_amount FROM receipt GROUP BY cust_id) r ON r.' at line 11

Comment: Can you give any solution plzzz

Comment: OK, Excuse me, i correct my answer, INNER JOIN added, try again

Comment: Tryed the new query,with these query dont get any result

Comment: but in sqlfiddle there was results ...,check the link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69950d/1/0

Comment: got results..Thanku very much ):

Answer (score 0):

you are using aggregate functions, then you should to use `group by`, but your `group by` is only over column `id`
you should to do `group by` over all columns not included in your aggregate function, it means:

```
group by customer.id, customer.name, customer.opeing_balance, customer.opening_balance_type
```

this is your query problem but i don't know it will be solve your problem or not. tell me

Comment: OK, try my new answer, i think it will help you

Answer (score 0):

```
please Try This query
select customer.id,customer.name,customer.opeing_balance,customer.opening_balance_type,sum(sale.total) as sum_total,sum(receipt.net_amount) as sum_net_amount, sum(sale_return.total_return) as sum_sale_return from customer as customer inner join sale as sale on customer.id=sale.cust_id inner join receipt as receipt on customer.id=receipt.cust_id inner join sale_return  as sale_return on customer.id=sale_return.cust_id group by customer.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `sale` table doesn't have an `id` column of its own, so your receipts and returns are associated with a customer but not a specific sale.  When you join the tables together, you get the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of all the sales with all the receipts and returns.  For example, you have a customer:

```
id name
26 neena
```

and she has two sales:

```
cust_id total
26      60
26      40
```

and she also has two returns:

```
cust_id total_return
26      15
26      20
```

and the join of these tables produces:

```
cust_id total total_return
26      60    15
26      60    20
26      40    15
26      40    20
```

Notice that each record from `sale` has been paired with each record from `sale_return`.  This is what database joins do, unless you include join conditions that limit which rows can be paired with which other rows.

You need to add an `id` column to the `sale` table and link the receipts and returns to a specific sale instead of just to a customer, so that when you join the tables you can use `on sale_return.sale_id = sale.id`.  And if there can be several receipts for a single sale, you probably need to add an `id` to `receipt` as well, and link each return to that instead of to a sale.

---

Here's a step-by-step look at how the results for Neena are produced:

First, you pull in Neena's record with `from customer`.  (I'm ignoring Shan's record.)  Initially you have just one row:

```
id name
26 neena
```

Then you join in her sales with `inner join sale on customer.id=sale.cust_id`.  This pairs the single customer row with all sales that have the same customer ID, so now you have two rows:

```
id name  cust_id total
26 neena 26      60
26 neena 26      40
```

Then you join in her receipts with `inner join receipt on customer.id=receipt.cust_id`.  This pairs *each* of the two rows above with all the receipts that have the same customer ID, so now you have *four* rows:

```
id name  cust_id total cust_id net_amount
26 neena 26      60    26      50
26 neena 26      60    26      10
26 neena 26      40    26      50
26 neena 26      40    26      10
```

Finally you join her returns with `inner join sale_return on customer.id=sale_return.cust_id`.  This pairs each of the four rows with all the returns that have the same customer ID, so now you have *eight* rows:

```
id name  cust_id total cust_id net_amount cust_id total_return
26 neena 26      60    26      50         26      15
26 neena 26      60    26      50         26      20
26 neena 26      60    26      10         26      15
26 neena 26      60    26      10         26      20
26 neena 26      40    26      50         26      15
26 neena 26      40    26      50         26      20
26 neena 26      40    26      10         26      15
26 neena 26      40    26      10         26      15
```

These eight rows are the result of your entire `from` clause, and they're the input to the `sum` functions.  The `sum(sale.total)` is 60+60+60+60+40+40+40+40, which is 400.  The `sum(receipt.net_amount)` is 50+50+10+10+50+50+10+10, which is 240, and the `sum(sale_return.total_return)` is 15+20+15+20+15+20+15+20, which is 140.

Comment: each table have id colums,buti dont mention it in stack over flow

Comment: Well, you need to change your `on` clauses to join each return with a specific sale or receipt, not with a whole customer (and thus *all* that customer's sales/receipts).  Otherwise you end up counting each record more than once in your totals.

Comment: I have already creted tables and coding in php.Any other idea?

Comment: id
name
opeing_balance
opening_balance_type
sum_total
sum_net_amount
sum_sale_return
26
neena
50
debit
400
240
140
27
shan
50
debit
400
80
120

Comment: I've added a more-detailed explanation of why you're getting those results.

Comment: Any solution for these issue? plzzz